# Marketing Cloud Populations - and possible use cases

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, filters, data-designer, populations

So far all Sales Cloud objects are synchronised via Marketing Cloud Connector to the Synchronised Data Extensions and have no relation to each other, meaning if we want to combine different objects in MC, there is a need to write SQL query.

Is there a way to use Populations instead, to already combine different synchronised data extensions, so users who are not familiar with SQL, could easily use Data Filters?

Or are there any other recommended approaches when dealing with Synchronised Data Extensions?